# Collection type as a cursor parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I need to do a cursor that receives a list as a parameter. I've tried this:

```
declare

type array_t is table of varchar(50); -- //also tried varray(10) instead of table

cursor c_cursor (p_list array_t) is
select 
    field_1
from 
    table_1
where 
    field_2 in p_list;

a_list array_t;

begin
    a_list := array_t('aaa',
        'bbb',
        'cccc',
        'ddd');

    for v_cursor in c_cursor(a_list) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_cursor.field_1);
    end loop;
end;
```

and I get the following error

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 21:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

I have read about using the `CREATE OR REPLACE` method but I cannot use `CREATE OR REPLACE` in this case (actually the database is read-only).

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Please add the expected output of the query.

Comment: Here's some example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249010/in-pl-sql-take-a-table-as-parameter-filter-it-and-return-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a SQL type not a pl/sql one, then use the `table` syntax to use it.

as you say you cannot create one, try the built in one on DBMS_OUTPUT.

```
SQL> create table table_1(field_1 varchar2(20), field_2 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into table_1 values ('test', 'aaa');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_1 values ('test2', 'cccc');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_1 values ('test3', 'x');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2  cursor c_cursor (p_list sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) is
  3  select /*+ cardinality(p, 10) */
  4      field_1
  5  from
  6      table_1 t
  7      inner join table(p_list) p
  8              on t.field_2 = p.column_value;
  9
 10  a_list sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY;
 11
 12  begin
 13      a_list := sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY('aaa',
 14          'bbb',
 15          'cccc',
 16          'ddd');
 17
 18      for v_cursor in c_cursor(a_list) loop
 19          dbms_output.put_line(v_cursor.field_1);
 20      end loop;
 21  end;
 22  /
test
test2
```

the `/*+ cardinality(p, 10) */` hint is to tell Oracle roughly how many rows will be in the array. put a representative number, or oracle will assume the array contains@ 8k rows which may cause a poor plan.

Comment: PLS-00201: identifier sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY must be declared    :(

Comment: @user1961089 what oracle version are you on?  you should be able to use a suitable type that you see with `select owner, type_name, coll_type, elem_type_name, upper_bound, length from all_coll_types where elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `type` separately using the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type array_t as table of varchar2(50);
```

Please try after that.

Answer (score 0):

This may help - Oracle PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  Type t_EmpNoArr IS VARRAY(20000) OF NUMBER(10) ;
  v_RetVal  t_EmpNoArr:= t_EmpNoArr();
  --
  FUNCTION retArray return t_EmpNoArr
  IS
    v_empnoArr t_EmpNoArr:= t_EmpNoArr();
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN ( SELECT empno FROM scott.emp )
    LOOP
      v_empnoArr.extend() ;
      v_empnoArr(v_empnoArr.count):= i.empno ;
    END LOOP;
  --
    FOR j IN 1..v_empnoArr.COUNT() LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_empnoArr(j));
    END LOOP;
  --
  RETURN v_empnoArr;
 END retArray;
 --
 BEGIN
   v_RetVal:= retArray();
 END;
 /
```